# How can I prevent avira antivirus for specific files?

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus, avira

When my computer starts and in 30 minutes intervals after the start, [Avira antivirus](http://www.avira.com/en/avira-free-antivirus) alerts me of these files as a `virus` but they are not. I created these files.

How can I prevent Avira antivirus from alerting me of specific files?

When starting the computer and after the start, Avira should never scan these files. I couldn't find any option on UI.

I use:

- `Windows 7 Professional x86`
- `Avira Free Antivirus Product version 12.1.9.1236`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the expert mode UI is an option to add exceptions for real time scanner and manual scanner.
Maybe you missed it?

[image: Avira Antivir UI]